# Constructor call as constructor parameter evaluates the declaration as a function pointer

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constructor, ambiguity

I just came across a weird ambiguity which took me ages to isolate since it suddenly appeared in the middle of some template mess after a minor API change.

The following example explores different ways to call a constructor (or so I thought), and some of them are quite obscure to me. In all of them I am trying to declare an object of type `A`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

// just a dummy class to use in the constructor of the next class
struct V {
   V(const std::vector<size_t> &){}
};

// the class we are interested in
struct A{
   A(const V &){}
   A(int, const V &){}
   A(const V &, int){}
   A(const V &, const V &){}
};

// a dummy function to delegate construction of V
V buildV(std::vector<size_t> &v){ return V(v); }

int main(){
   std::vector<size_t> v = {1024,1024};
   V vw(v);

   // I am using macros to make the constructor argument more visible
   #define BUILD_A(X) { A a(X); std::cerr << typeid(a).name() << std::endl; }
   #define BUILD_A2(X,Y) { A a(X, Y); std::cerr << typeid(a).name() << std::endl; }

   // All of the following call the constructor of A with different parameters
   // the comment on the right shows the type of the declared a
   /* 1 */ BUILD_A( vw )                       // object
   /* 2 */ BUILD_A( V(v) )                     // function pointer
   /* 3 */ BUILD_A( v )                        // object
   /* 4 */ BUILD_A( std::vector<size_t>() )    // function pointer
   /* 5 */ BUILD_A( (V)V(v) )                  // object
   /* 6 */ BUILD_A( ( V(v) ) )                 // object
   /* 7 */ BUILD_A( buildV(v) )                // object

   /* 8 */ BUILD_A2(10,V(v))                   // object
   /* 9 */ BUILD_A2(V(v),10)                   // object
   /* 10 */ BUILD_A2(vw,V(v))                  // object
   /* 11 */ BUILD_A2(V(v), vw)                 // object

   /* 12 */ //BUILD_A2(V(v), V(v))             // doesn't compile
   /* 13 */ BUILD_A2(V(v), (V)V(v))            // object
}
```

The second and fourth examples seem to declare a function pointer instead of an object, which raises a couple of questions:

1. Why is `V(v)` interpreted as a type instead of an object for `A a(V(v))` ?
2. How is casting back `V(v)` to `(V)V(v)` interpreted differently?
3. Why is the compiler not able to infer the cast itself?
4. Does the double parenthesis `((...))` in 6 have a semantic meaning there or is it just helping to disambiguate the parser? I don't see how it could be a precedence problem.
5. If `V(v)` evaluates to a Type instead of an object, why is `A a(V(v), V(v))` not legal in 12?
6. It's funny that adding a scalar value as well suddenly makes the compiler realize the other is an object too in 8 to 11.
7. Did I miss any syntax that would reproduce the ambiguity? Do you know of any other confusing cases?
8. Shouldn't GCC warn me that there might be a problem there? Clang does.

Thanks,

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the **most vexing parse**: the attempted declaration is parsed as a function declaration.

The C++ rule is, if something can be parsed as a function declaration, it will be.

There are some workarounds, such as writing `A a(( V(v) ))`, which cannot be parsed as a declaration of a function `a` with a `V` argument and returning `A`.

---

Regarding warnings, the standard does not require any diagnostic for this. After all, the potential ambiguity has been resolved. In favor of function. :-)

Comment: That explains most of my points. I am still not sure why `A a(V(v), V(v))` wouldn't be legal as well. Couldn't it be a function taking two  unnamed arguments?